# Let $f(x)$ be a thrice differentiable function in $[a,b]$, and $a<k_1<k_2<k_3<k_4<k_5<b$ and $f(a)=f(b)=-2,f(k_1)=f(k_3)=3,f(k_2)=f(k_4)=-3,f(k_5)=-1$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ be a thrice differentiable function in $[a,b]$, and $a<k_1<k_2<k_3<k_4<k_5<b$ and $f(a)=f(b)=-2,f(k_1)=f(k_3)=3,f(k_2)=f(k_4)=-3,f(k_5)=-1$, then min number of root of the equation $f(x)f'''(x)+f'(x)f''(x)=0$ in $[a,b]$

Graphing the function $f(x)$ (rough sketch) gives a *minimum* of 4 roots.

Also the given expression can be written as $$g(x)=\frac {d(f(x)f''(x))}{dx}$$

Now to satisfy the minimum root condition, let us assume that the roots of $f(x)$ and $f''(x)$ coincide. so $f(x)f''(x)$ will have a minimum of four roots.

Now since the derivative will have one root less than the original function, $g(x)$ will have at least 3 roots.

However the correct answer is 4.

I suspect this assumption of mine was wrong

> let us assume that the roots of $f(x)$ and $f''(x)$ coincide

But I am not able to prove that it is wrong. Is there a proper solution for this?

Comment: Is $k_1<k_2<k_3<k_4<k_5$ as well?

Comment: @LegNaiB yes, I will make the required changes